# Armature Detaches When Joining Objects

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I am trying to headhack a model, where both the head and body have armature.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, the armature are joined, but the head moves away and detaches itself from the armature. How do I avoid this?

Comment: because, as your head bone is now part of another armature, I guess the head stop being controlled by it and comes back to its initial position. I don't know if you have any solution, you need to reparent the head to its bone with Weight Paint mode or with the Assign button below the Vertex Groups list.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the head and the body share the same name of any vertex group, in that case rename one of them before making any joint. Then you should be able to join the armatures, join the meshes and have everything working as expected.

Remember that the order in which you select the two objects to join matters: the selected object will be part of the ACTIVE object, and will inherit its name, so - if something doesn't work, probably the armature modifier of the joined model is pointing to the armature with the wrong name, and you will have to simply choose the correct name in the modifier field.

All weights should remain untouched.

At now, as Moonboots said, the head has an armature modifier that is pointing to a non existing armature, if you change this, selecting the new jointed armature in the head's armature modifier, the head should return in its correct position.